# CSVReader is skipping the first line

Tags: acumatica

I'm using the CSVReader object, but it is skipping the first line. Is there any way to prevent this?

My code:

```
if (UploadFile.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
{
    StringBuilder filetext = new StringBuilder();


    PX.SM.FileInfo info = PXContext.SessionTyped<PXSessionStatePXData>().FileInfo["MyFileImportSessionKey"] as PX.SM.FileInfo;

    Byte[] bytes = info.BinData;

    using (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(bytes, Encoding.ASCII.CodePage))
    {
        reader.Reset();
        filetext.Append("FIRST:" + reader.GetValue(0) + " DONE" + Environment.NewLine);

        while (reader.MoveNext())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.IndexKeyPairs.Count; i++)
            {
                filetext.Append(reader.GetValue(i));
            }
            filetext.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("MyFileImportSessionKey");
    }

    CurrentDocument.Ask(filetext.ToString(), MessageButtons.OK);
}
```

This always shows all lines after the first line. I understand that typically the first line is a header and would want to be ignored, but in my case I need all lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is definitely handled as a special case.

I believe it's exposed in the IndexKeyPairs public collection.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> headerColumn in reader.IndexKeyPairs)
{
   int headerColumIndex = headerColumn.Key;
   string headerColumnCellValue = headerColumn.Value;
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks HB!